# html putting a div in between td tags on z axis

Tags: html, css

I have a table, but I would like to put my div tag in front of one too, but behind another, in the same table. I would like to put the div with the id "backDrop" behind the td with the id "td1", and the td with the id "menu", everything else should be behind the div

```
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr style="z-index:1">
    <td style="width:91.0vw;" id="header">
      <h1>Tyler Silva E-Portfolio</h1>
    </td>
    <td  onclick="openNav()"id="td1" style="background-color:#3953a5;z-index:initial;">
      <img style="width:8vw;" id="logo" src="img/logo.png" onclick="openNav()"/>
    </td>
    <div id="backDrop" style="opacity:0" onclick="alert('hello')"></div>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--body-->
      <h1 style="color:white">
        hello world
    </td>

    <td id="nav" rowspan="2">
      <div id="menu"><p>M<br />E<br />N<br />U<br /></p></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><!--footer--></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and my css is

```
body
{
margin:0;
background-color:#55505c;
}

#header
{
    height:8vw;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#77b6ea;
    z-index:-1
}

h1
{
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:3vw;
    margin-top:1.5vw;
}

#logo
{
vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;

}
td
{
    padding:0
}

#nav
{
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#3953a5;
    font-size:8vw;
    z-index:100000;
}

#backDrop
{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:initial;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML. Only `<td>` or `<th>` can be a child of a `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @j08691 said placing div between a table row tag in invalid HTML. What you are after is something like this:

```css
body
{
margin:0;
background-color:#55505c;
}

#header
{
    height:8vw;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#77b6ea;
    z-index:-1
}

h1
{
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:3vw;
    margin-top:1.5vw;
}

#logo
{
vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;

}
td
{
    padding:0
}

#nav
{
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#3953a5;
    font-size:8vw;
    z-index:100000;
}

#backDrop
{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:99;
    opacity:0;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="backDrop" style="opacity:0" onclick="alert('hello')"></div>
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:91.0vw;" id="header">
      <h1>Tyler Silva E-Portfolio</h1>
    </td>
    <td  onclick="openNav()"id="td1" style="background-color:#3953a5;z-index:initial;">
      <img style="width:8vw;" id="logo" src="img/logo.png" onclick="openNav()"/>
    </td>
    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--body-->
      <h1 style="color:white">
        hello world
    </h1>
    </td>

    <td id="nav" rowspan="2">
      <div id="menu"><p>M<br />E<br />N<br />U<br /></p></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><!--footer--></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The div has been placed placed above everything using z-index and position.

Is this what you were after?

Comment: close, I want it above everything except the menu and the logo(td tags with the ids "td1", and "menu")

Comment: Give the table a zindex of 99 and add another table after your first one with the rest of the contents inside that table. That should fix it.

Comment: i did eventually, i had to mess with a lot of css to get it to open and not look really bad, but i did it

Comment: Search for 'syfer does web' online and you can find me if you need help later